# Cufon: changing font-weight on hover

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon

I am using Cufon to embed `<a>` tags with the 'Print Clearly' typeface.

On the hover state of the `<a>` tag I would like the text to change to bold, how can I do this with Cufon?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/print-clearly_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   Cufon.replace('a', fontWeight: 'normal',
    hover: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that you cannot add a hover
>   effect to an element that has already
>   been replaced. You can, however,
>   replace the hoverable element first
>   and then the parent element after
>   that. The hover effect will still
>   apply.

But you can setup it on load:

```
Cufon('h1', {
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    hover: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
});
```

[Further reading](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/styling).

Comment: do I need to specify a second font for the bold? I have tried as above, and is appearing as the default browser font but the bold on hover is working. When I don't try the hover, the font replacement works properly. I have added my code above